# Word for somebody who participates in a riot?

Tags: single-word-requests

I could not find an official definition of rioter anywhere, so I am unsure if that is the correct word. I'm looking specifically at a word for someone who is actively participate in a riot, so not necessarily just a protester.

Comment: "Rioter" would be the normal word to use when identifying someone participating in a riot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know you can use the word "rioter" also you could say "revolter" in some cases or "marcher"

Answer (score 2):

According to [this webpage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rioter), a person who participates in a riot is a rioter. The word rioter is the noun used when talking about a person who participates in a riot. However, other terms you could use can be found [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rioter).

Answer (score 1):

Candidates:

**malcontent, rebel, traitor, mutineer, rioter
rebel(s), refusenik(s), hunger strike(s,r,rs), insurrectionist(s)**